# Select * not returning with foreign keys in table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have populated all my databases with the information needed before i created the final table with my foreign key constraints referencing them but when i view the final table with a select * from mytbl my foreign key values are coming back as null values. i have been going through this site and my textbook for an hour trying to figure out what i have wrong but i am not seeing it. here is my code that i have used for the database.

```
Create Database Donutsrus;

Create table customer
(CustomerID int not null auto_increment,
FirstName varchar(255) not null,
LastName varchar(255) not null,
StreetAddress char(255) not null,
Apartment varchar(255) not null,
City varchar(255) not null,
State varchar(2) not null,
ZipCode int(9) not null,
HomePhone int(10) not null,
MobilePhone int(10) not null,
OtherPhone int(10) not null,
Primary Key (CustomerID));

insert into Customer 
(FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, Apartment, City, State,
ZipCode, HomePhone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone)
Values ("Ken", "Weger", "StreetAddress", "Apartment", "City", 
"ST", 123456789, 1111111111, 222222222, 333333333);

Create Table Donut
(Quantity int(255) not null,
DonutID int(255) not null auto_increment,
Name varchar(255) not null,
Description varchar(255) not null,
UnitPrice decimal(3,2) not null,
LineTotal Decimal(10,2) not null,
Primary Key (DonutID));

insert into Donut (Quantity, Name, Description, UnitPrice, LineTotal)
Values ("1", "Plain", "Plain Donut", "1.50", "1.50"),
("5", "Glazed", "Glazed Donut", "1.75", "8.75"),
("12", "Cinnamon", "Cinnamon Donut", "1.75", "21.00"),
("3", "Chocolate", "Chocolate Donut", "1.75", "5.25"),
("4", "Sprinkle", "Sprinkle Donut", "1.75", "7.00"),
("5", "Gluten-Free", "Gluten-Free Donut", "2.00", "10.00");

Create Table DonutOrder
(DonutOrderID int(255) not null auto_increment,
CustomerID int(255),
DonutID int(255),
`Date` date not null,
SpecialHandlingNotes Varchar(255),
Primary Key (DonutOrderID),
Index Customer (customerid),
Foreign Key (CustomerID) References Customer(CustomerID),
Index Donut (donutid),
Foreign Key (DonutID) References Donut(DonutID));

Insert into DonutOrder (`Date`, SpecialHandlingNotes)
Values ("20140506", "Please Include Plates and Napkins");
```

If I add a not null syntax after customerid and donutid in the donutorder database i get this

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`donutsrus`.`donutorder`, CONSTRAINT `donutorder_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES `customer` (`CustomerID`)).
```

Comment: is your database empty yet? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92c2c I see no problem with fiddle

Comment: In the code you provide you don't insert the values for the foreign key values. You need to do that. The database cannot know which records to link to if you don't tell it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should insert values for the foreign key fields. For instance:

```
Insert into DonutOrder (
            `Date`,
            SpecialHandlingNotes,
            CustomerId,
            DonutId
            )
values (    "20140506",
            "Please Include Plates and Napkins", 
            (select CustomerId from Customer where MobilePhone = 222222222),
            (select DonutId    from Donut    where Name = 'Plain')
            );
```

Comment: thank you i have been looking for this type of help i could not find anyplace that explained this.